# How to convert Joda Localdate to Joda DateTime?

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I'm trying to simply add TimeZone information back into a LocalDate before performing some more calculations. The LocalDate came from using the ObjectLab LocalDateCalculator to add days to an existing DateTime but the method needs to return a modified ReadableInstant to form an Interval which I can then inspect.

The code I'm trying amounts to a conversion of Joda LocalDate to Joda DateTime:

```
LocalDate contextLocalBusinessDate = calculator.getCurrentBusinessDate();
DateTime businessDateAsInContextLocation = new DateTime(contextLocalBusinessDate, contextTimeZone);
```

The error I get is from Joda's conversion system:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No instant converter found for type: org.joda.time.LocalDate
        at org.joda.time.convert.ConverterManager.getInstantConverter(ConverterManager.java:165)
        at org.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime.<init>(BaseDateTime.java:147)
        at org.joda.time.DateTime.<init>(DateTime.java:192)
```

I'm looking for a fix to this problem, or a workaround that results in an accurate Interval with full timezone information.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There are various methods on [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) for this, including:

- [`LocalDate::toDateTimeAtCurrentTime()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtCurrentTime--)
- [`LocalDate::toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay--)
- [`LocalDate::toDateTime( LocalTime )`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTime-org.joda.time.LocalTime-)
- [`LocalDate::toDateTime( LocalTime , DateTimeZone )`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTime-org.joda.time.LocalTime-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-)

You have to be explicit about what you want the time component to be in the resulting `DateTime` object, which is why `DateTime`'s general-conversion constructor can't do it.

Comment: Spot on. One thing to be aware of: toDateTimeAtStartOfDay doesn't mean "midnight"... some time zones implement daylight saving changes to skip from midnight to 1am.

Comment: You might conclude as I did, that which of the methods (that all return DateTime, like those here) that you choose doesn't really matter:  The fact that a LocalDate was used should imply it was coded without any intent for a particular time on that date, so whatever time you give it in the conversion on that date is just as good as any other time on that date.  The key is that giving it a time is what allows the conversion to LocalDate, and it doesn't matter what the time is (since you started with a LocalDate that didn't care about time) if all you need is some sort of DateTime.

Comment: Please help - I cannot see any of this methods on my LocalDate object. What does the '::' notation mean in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

A common way to convert a `LocalDate` to `ZonedDateTime` is to first convert it to `LocalDateTime` with `00:00` hours using [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay--) and then combine with a `ZoneId`. An alternative to `LocalDate#atStartOfDay` is `LocalDate#atTime(LocalTime.MIN)`.

Note that [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) is another variant of `atStartOfDay`. However, it may not return a `ZonedDateTime` with `00:00` hours on the day of [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) transition.

You can convert from `ZonedDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime` using [`ZonedDateTime#toOffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toOffsetDateTime--).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        // Note: Change the ZoneId as applicable e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")

        ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-11T00:00+01:00[Europe/London]
2021-07-11T00:00+01:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/keJTv7)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>